# Only variable references should be returned by reference - Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, apache2, codeigniter-2

After the server PHP upgrade I am getting the following error with PHP Version 5.6.2 on Apache 2.0

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 257
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 475, accepted):

Edit filename: core/Common.php, line number: 257

Before

```
return $_config[0] =& $config;
```

After

```
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

## Update

Added by NikiC

In PHP assignment expressions always return the assigned value. So $_config[0] =& $config returns $config - but not the variable itself, but a copy of its value. And returning a reference to a temporary value wouldn't be particularly useful (changing it wouldn't do anything).

### Update

This fix has been merged into CI 2.2.1 (https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/69b02d0f0bc46e914bed1604cfbd9bf74286b2e3). It's better to upgrade rather than modifying core framework files.

Comment: hiya... kind to explain why do this?
it works and i don't know why :p

Comment: @GuyFreakz In PHP assignment expressions always return the assigned **value**. So `$_config[0] =& $config` returns `$config` - but not the variable itself, but a copy of its value. And returning a reference to a temporary value wouldn't be particularly useful (changing it wouldn't do anything).

Comment: yeah... that's good one! I have no idea why it could give that things out to be shown... :D

Comment: this has been merged in ci 2.2.1 `https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/69b02d0f0bc46e914bed1604cfbd9bf74286b2e3`. It's better to upgrade like @Chad has mentioned.

Comment: I'm on an older version of codeigniter (2.0.2) when I try this fix on line 243 (that's where it shows up in my version) -- I get a php 500 error. Any idea how I can get this working?

Comment: Didnt work for me, hade do declare it to an another return value: $_config[0] =& $config;
  $returnValue = $_config[0];
  return $returnValue;

Comment: Just did this and i get a "HTTP ERROR 500"

Answer (score 8):

this has been modified in codeigniter 2.2.1...usually not best practice to modify core files, I would always check for updates and 2.2.1 came out in Jan 2015

Answer (score 1):

It's not a better idea to override the core.common file of codeigniter. Because that's the more tested and system files....

I make a solution for this problem.
In your ckeditor_helper.php file
 **line- 65**

```
if($k !== end (array_keys($data['config']))) {
       $return .= ",";
}
```

Change this to-->

```
 $segment = array_keys($data['config']);
    if($k !== end($segment)) {
           $return .= ",";
    }
```

I think this is the best solution and then your problem notice will dissappear.