# CodeIgniter Error: variable references

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've deployed my source code in XAMPP. I'm getting following errors.

> Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\3c_app\public_html\system\core\Common.php on line 257
>   Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\3c_app\public_html\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 233.

My source files are:

**Common.php**

```
// Are any values being dynamically replaced?
    if (count($replace) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($replace as $key => $val)
        {
            if (isset($config[$key]))
            {
                $config[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    return $_config[0] =& $config;
}
```

line 257 is:    `return $_config[0] =& $config;` and

**Codeigniter.php**

```
// Fetch the config file
    if ( ! file_exists($file_path))
    {
        exit('The configuration file does not exist.');
    }

    require($file_path);
```

line 233: `if ( ! file_exists($file_path))`

Can any one help???

Comment: You shouldn't change core files. What application code causes this error? Can you edit your question and post your app controller code that leads to error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only variable references should be returned by reference - Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348879/only-variable-references-should-be-returned-by-reference-codeigniter)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this one:

Change it in your Common.php

```
if (count($replace) > 0){
    foreach ($replace as $key => $val){
        if (isset($config[$key])){
            $config[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
}

$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

See also here , for more reference : [Only variable references should be returned by reference - Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348879/only-variable-references-should-be-returned-by-reference-codeigniter) . I hope this helps.

Answer (score 16):

In **Common.php** Change this

```
return $_config[0] =& $config;
```

to this

```
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

Problem is with assigning and returning data.

Answer (score 2):

If your code is still not working, then **try this**.

```
$_config[1]=& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

Comment: This results in:
"A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: subclass_prefix

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 237"

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter itself fixed that error now.

You just update current updated version of Codeigniter in [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter).

It will solve your error.