# How to fix Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference in

Tags: php, notice, e-notices

i am using php script got from torrenteditor to create torrent files , but when i create new torrent files, using specified method, torrent files gets created but i get lots of notices ., like this

**Only variable references should be returned by reference in myfile.php  on line 319**

on this line

```
return new BEncode_End();
```

which is specified as another class as

```
class BEncode_End
{
    public function get_type()
    {
        return 'end';
    }
}
```

so how can i fix this notices ?

i am pretty new to classes , so dont know where to start.

complete script/code uploaded here http://pastebin.com/L6ktvrne , line 319

i am using

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` fixes it

Comment: @adeneo i guess, it doesnt fixes, it , it ignores/ hides it, thanks i am looking for fix , so i can use this in production and not worried about ignoring other notices too,

Comment: Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348879/only-variable-references-should-be-returned-by-reference-codeigniter try: `$cl = new BEncode_End(); return $cl;`

Comment: @OfirBaruch strange, it did fixed the issue of notices. Thanks.

Comment: Would it be ok if I'd add it as a solution for your approval?

Comment: @OfirBaruch yes, please. you have a GO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the notice you get and on an [answer to another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348879/only-variable-references-should-be-returned-by-reference-codeigniter):

> In PHP assignment expressions always return the assigned value. So
>   $_config[0] =& $config returns $config - but not the variable itself,
>   but a copy of its value. And returning a reference to a temporary
>   value wouldn't be particularly useful (changing it wouldn't do
>   anything).

Changing your code from:

```
return new BEncode_End();
```

To:

```
$cl = new BEncode_End();
return $cl;
```

Should solve your problem.

Comment: It indeed solved my problem, and i even fixed more occurrences of similar code.,  thanks