# PHP Codeigniter Blank White screen after change system/core/common.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

First of all, my web return blank white screen,after add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to `index.php` the error is appear :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 257
```

then, using this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348879/only-variable-references-should-be-returned-by-reference-codeigniter/28348880#28348880), i change `system/core/common.php` file on line 257. But After change it, **my web comeback to blank screen**.

Please help me to solve this...

FYI, my `index.php` :

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);

        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

I have tried to change ENVIRONMENT to development, but still face blank screen...

Comment: this is because version problem in some case. Actually the error is not happened in that particular file

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal is it possible to downgrade php when using XAMPP ?

Comment: set display_errors=1 in your php.ini... something else must be happening.

Comment: @Clayton i just change to display_erros=1 or display_errors=On, but no change...

Comment: are you echo'ing any values? Is that literally everything in your index.php? maybe it's not displaying anything because you have nothing to display? post more code...

Comment: @Clayton i'm not doing echo and too many codes to display here, however this code on my server run smoothly, only on local computer i face this error....

Comment: is your database username/password configured correctly? if you view the source of the 'blank' screen do you see anything?

Comment: @Clayton database still have same configuration to my server, but it should show any error, right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99094/discussion-between-clayton-and-user2226388).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. But instead doing this you should change your ENVIRONMENT Constant as your requirement. If you want to show error change `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');` to `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');`

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;

    default:
        exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Edit filename: core/Common.php, line number: 257

Before

return $_config[0] =& $config; 

After

$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

Comment: please check the ENVIRONMENT defined in index.php if it is production or testing change to developement                                                                            define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

Comment: please mention that change in question

Answer (score 0):

I have undergone similar issue and modified the  257th line of `system/core/common.php`. if it is not mentioned as below change it so-

```
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

[Only variable references should be returned by reference - Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348879/only-variable-references-should-be-returned-by-reference-codeigniter)

[Codeigniter displays a blank page instead of error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages)

Comment: Thank you but I have done this change, but comeback to blank screen

Comment: can you just check whether  `$db['default']['db_debug']` set to `TRUE`

Comment: yes, it true : `$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;`

Answer (score 0):

This is default settings of Codeigniter. ***Keep it has it is***.

```
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

> > **Just you have to do is, in `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'XYZ');` you can change environment with your purpose.**

1. **development** - Shows errors of your system and ***suit for developers***
2. **testing** - This is for ***testing purpose***
3. **production** - This is when ***site is live/hosted***. So no errors will appear in view. Just skip all and run smoothly.

---

> > When `error_reporting(E_ALL);` is there you **no need to set** `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Bcz **its shows the all errors as well**.
> >
> > Hence **in `production` do not set** `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Bcz **`production` is used to when site is hosted.**

Comment: Hi, it still not work, i just download fresh package from server then just change index.php parameter, but still face error...

Comment: `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');`  to  `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` only change this....

Comment: as i said before in my asking, an error then blank screen, please see my question...