# How to solve pyrocms installation issues in windows?

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I recently downloaded pyrocms(it is probably the latest version). But when I try to install it I get error saying "Only variable references should be returned by reference" on "core/common.php" file on line 272. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Simple copy/paste of that error message should give you something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348879/only-variable-references-should-be-returned-by-reference-codeigniter#answer-28348880) in google or in SoF search form field.

Comment: yeah, I solved it. Just had to change "return $_config[0] =& $config;" code to "$_config[0] =& $config; return $_config[0];"
Thank you for the response.