# When CI project is transferred from wamp server to xampp server Uncaught error occurs in core/common.php(line 257)

Tags: codeigniter-3

[When I run CI project this error occurs,Can anyone help me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThlrO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlV9V.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have different versions of PHP AND you are running a version of codeigniter < 2.2.1

In Version 2.2.1 and above, this was fixed.

If you cannot upgrade it for any reason, the fix is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348879/only-variable-references-should-be-returned-by-reference-codeigniter)

I have tested this on PHP 5.6.19 and CI 2.1.3 which displays the issue. CI 2.2.1 and 3.1.0 do not. I've not tested all the others in between.

Comment: So did that help you any? Did you get it sorted out?