# Troube with migrate an codeigniter system

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to migrate an codeigniter system for my localhost, but i'm receiving this message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 257

Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema-emisa\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 233
```

I've download the following pages from the host:

> application ~ 
>   public_html ~ 
>   system

---

I changed the enters of the BD for the corrects on my localhost but still didnt work. I have to do some setting or download something else?

The server have this estructure:

[image]

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348879/only-variable-references-should-be-returned-by-reference-codeigniter).

Comment: @Tpojka it worked for me, but i'm still with the error message: 
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema-emisa\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 233

Comment: Check `.htaccess` and `APPPATH.'config/config.php'` to see if any value from online server still there and need to be changed to localhost values.

Answer (score 0):

One quick fix needs to be done.

Go to your system/core/Common.php file.
And search for `return $_config[0] =& $config;`

and replace this content with either of the following two snippets:

```
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

OR

```
return isset($_config[0][$item]) ? $_config[0][$item] : NULL;
```

Both of the above given pieces of codes will work.