# I have a installation set I want to set up this but it gives error below in image (Error in Commmon.php)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Error in this line

```
return $_config[0] =& $config;
```

when I changed this to

```
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

then it gives me http error 500

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference Filename: core/Common.php Line Number: 257

It give like that error and also my server php version is updated 7.1

Comment: I think you need to downgrade your PHP version or need to upgrade you CI version

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 257 It give like that error and also my server php version is updated 7.1

Comment: There are few answers to this question already in stackoverflow (One among them : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348879/only-variable-references-should-be-returned-by-reference-codeigniter). But yes, it's a true fact as @M.Hemant said, consider downgrading your PHP to 5.x or upgrading your CI.